# execute python script written in yaml with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I'm trying to execute python line written in YAML file with YAML scalar value as a variable.

My code:

```
with open("file.yaml", "r") as file:
    yaml_ = yaml.load(file)

eval(yaml_['Code'])
```

`file.yaml`:

```
ToPrint:
  var: something
Code: print("{{var}}")
```

Output is: `{{var}}` (my expected output: `something` ).

Is there a way to print YAML field that way?

Comment: Show your real code and the complete error message.

Comment: that is my real code, if found mistake in my code so I updated all

Comment: @xyz There are no fields in a YAML file, that concept is not in the YAML specification. What you are referring to is a scalar (string) value in a mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the YAML file to read:

```
ToPrint:
  var: something
Code: print("{var}".format(**d['ToPrint']))
```

And since you are using Python3 also use `Path`:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
d = yaml.load(Path('file.yaml'))
eval(d['Code'])
```

which gives:

```
something
```

Please note that the variable `d`  has to be the same as the one in the value
for `Code`

The use of `{{var}}` looks more like a (jinja2) template. You cannot 
directly eval those, you would need to expand the template and then all 
eval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToPrint` as local variables in `eval`:

```
with open("file.yaml", "r") as file:
    yaml_ = yaml.load(file)

eval(yaml_['Code'], yaml_['ToPrint'])
```

And the yaml-file:

```
ToPrint:
  var: something
Code: print(f"{var}")
```

Comment: I got error: `TypeError: globals must be a real dict; try eval(expr, {}, mapping)`

Answer (score 0):

extended Daniel's answer:

yaml-file:

```
Const:
    c1: 10
    c2: 20
Expression: var1 * var2 + c1 / c2
```

code:

```
import yaml

with open("formula.yaml", "r") as file:
    yaml_ = yaml.load(file)

res = eval(yaml_['Expression'], 
           {'var1':4, 'var2':2}, 
           yaml_['Const'])
print(res)
```